# HorizontalScrollView -> LinearLayout -> TextView — scrollbar size doesn't reset after text change

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, scroll, android-view

I'm facing with strange behavior of my very first android app: I have a `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. This `TextView` is updated via the `setText(myObject.getMyArrayList().get(0))`. Also I have three buttons: `MoreText`, `ClearText` and `RecordText`.

When I press the `MoreText` button, it just append some text to the `0` element of my `ArrayList`. At this moment, when the `TextView` become larger, the scrollbar appears on the screen.

When I press the `ClearText` button, it **set**s the `0` element of my `ArrayList` to DEFAULT_SHORT_STRING. At that moment, the `TextView` shrinks to the default string size and the scrollbar is disappeared.

When I press the `RecordText` button, it **add** DEFAULT_SHORT_STRING to the `0` element of the my `ArrayList` (checked with debugger). **And what strange is**, at this moment the `TextView` shrinks to the default string size, but scrollbar still being on the screen with the last known size. Moreover, if I press the `MoreText` button again and again, scrollbar will be the same until `TextView` overgrown it.

Answer (score 0):

Although mentioned behavior still unexplainable, the problem was solved by removing `LinearLayout` from the chain. Probably something with `LinearLayout` width, or with updating.